# java automation selenium,how to identify the locator in google chrome? except developers tool

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

i want to identify the web element for the selenium script using any plug in example in firefox we use a firepath . is plug in for chrome to identify the webelement .i have tried with developers tool but using developers tool not getting clear locator?

Comment: Please clarify your question and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers just right-click on chosen element on webpage and choose 'Inspect'/'Inspect element' etc and the developer tools would open with marked HTML code for that element.

If that html code didn't show you unique ID for that element it means that you need to:

- use xpath to find element by unique text inside (dont use xpath is slow)
- or css selector to find it by unique attribute of that element
- or asks dev team to add proper unique id/attibute to that element, and thats the best option